# Angular binding is not working in custom directive for local scope variables calculated using passed data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, 2-way-object-databinding

In above example when I change the value array passed to directive from controller, all the changes gets reflected in the directive html. I mean I can see the changes in the UI.

But changes in the value of `$scope.message` variable doesn’t get reflected, even though the value of `$scope.message` is being calculated from the value of `$scope.myData`, whose value is getting changed using `$timeout` in the parent controller
To see those changes in `$scope.message`, you need to watch the array using `$watchCollection`. My questions are,

1. Why angular’s binding is not working for `$scope.myData` normally?
2. What are other “known” corner cases where angular’s binding doesn’t work?

Below is the code snippet

```
(function(){
    angular.module("csjoshi04.2waybinding",[])
            .controller("ParentCtrl",["$scope", "$timeout", function($scope, $timeout){
                $scope.myCars = ["Ford", "BMW", "Toyata"];
                $timeout(function(){
                    $scope.myCars.push("Honda");
                }, 3000);
            }])
            .directive("showMyData",function(){
                return {
                    restrict: "E",
                    scope: {
                        myData : "="
                    },
                    controller : ["$scope", function($scope){
                        $scope.message = ($scope.myData.indexOf("Honda") > -1 && $scope.myData.length >= 4) ? "1 out of 4 cars is always Honda": "OOPS, no honda cars";
                    }],
                    template : '<div>{{message}}</div><ul ng-repeat="data in myData"><li>{{data}}</li></ul>'
                }
            })
})()
```

Below is html

```
<body ng-controller="ParentCtrl"><show-my-data my-data="myCars" ></show-my-data></body>
```

To make above directive work, I made below changes

```
directive("showMyData",function(){
                return {
                    restrict: "E",
                    scope: {
                        myData : "="
                    },
                    controller : ["$scope", function($scope){
                        $scope.message = ($scope.myData.indexOf("Honda") > -1 && $scope.myData.length >= 4) ? "1 out of 4 cars is always Honda": "OOPS, no honda cars";
                        $scope.$watchCollection(function(){
                            return $scope.myData;
                        }, function(new1, old){
                            $scope.message = ($scope.myData.indexOf("Honda") > -1 && $scope.myData.length >= 4) ? "1 out of 4 cars is always Honda": "OOPS, no honda cars";
                        });
                    }],
                    template : '<div>{{message}}</div><ul ng-repeat="data in myData"><li>{{data}}</li></ul>'
                }
            })
```

here is the link to plunkr.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xiGBra?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't call this a *"corner case"* of the data binding in angular.

Angular's data-binding works by continuously checking the values attached to $scope. It's cool but it's not magic, in an imperative language like JavaScript statement 
`$scope.message = condition ? "message": "another message";` will not in itself suggest that the expression would be re-evaluated ever again. Angular initializes the controller only once per attachment to template and that is exactly how many times the statement in the above example will get evaluated. **Once.** After that it's just another `$scope` variable whose value is either "message" or "another message" and that's how it's going to stay if we don't change it ourself.

You have identified the problem yourself. The value of `$scope.message` depends on `$scope.myData` but without the `$watchCollection` there is nothing to keep this linkage up to date. `$watchCollection`, on the other hand, will keep re-evaluating first the `$scope.myData;` and then the `$scope.message = ...` functions because that's what angular makes it to do.

Personally, though, I'd do it with a function getter instead of assigning the value to `$scope` and manually keeping it up to date. That's closer to what you were originally trying to do anyway.

```
.directive("showMyData",function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
           myData : "="
        },
        controller : ["$scope", function($scope){
            $scope.getMessage = function(){
                return ($scope.myData.indexOf("Honda") > -1 && $scope.myData.length >= 4) ? "1 out of 4 cars is always Honda": "OOPS, no honda cars";
            };    
        }],
        template : '<div>{{getMessage()}}</div><ul ng-repeat="data in myData"><li>{{data}}</li></ul>'
     }
})
```

Now that we are using a function call instead of a simple value, the expression that creates the message gets re-evaluated over and over again, updating the view when necessary.

Comment: this is a really good solution. It also helps in not using $scope.$watch/Collection. One question though, in this problem why a getter function always gets evaluated whereas message not?

Comment: They both get evaluated. 
With `$scope.message` the controller code will run once and `$scope.message` will be "OOPS, no honda cars" because when it runs there are no hondas. Angular will keep checking what the value of `$scope.message` is but it won't change. Angular can't access or re-use your code `$scope.message = ($scope.myData.indexOf("Honda")...`. 
That indexOf check will run once and then its gone, just the result gets assigned to `message`, not the whole statement.

Comment: That's just how statements work in many programming languages. But functions are different. The code inside them can and will get re-evaluated as many times as we want. Unlike with the simple message value, angular can call the function over and over again, asking it to re-evaluate the value.

Comment: thanks. I got it. My bad.. how can I forget the simple concept that the value of $scope.message is set when code ran for the first time. and no matter how many times angular checks for a change in value, its always gonna be same.